# How set distances in a specific layout using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to accomplish the following:

[image]

If the container is wider than the image below than the map pin icon should right align, while the close (x) icon should remain next to the address.  Correspondingly, the text should be on a single line if it can fit.

I need to have a gray background that encompasses 1st and 2nd flexbox items.  I am getting something close but not quite right.  There is space between those items.

What am I missing?

I have the following layout & css:

```css
.address-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 38px;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.address-pin-icon {
  order: 3;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
  padding: 5px;  
}

.address-text {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 0px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.address-close {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  order: 2;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.address-close > img:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: white">
      <div class="address-container">
        <span class="address-pin-icon"><img src="https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/map-pin.svg" height="18" /></span>
        <span class="address-text">1533 Sylvia Dr, Bristol, Maine</span>
        <span class="address-close"><img src="https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/close.svg" height="18" /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand your question, but I recreated some stuff in a codepen that I think does what you need:

https://codepen.io/dustinkeeton/pen/yQXMyo

the short of it is that I wrapped the `address-text` and `address-close` elements in their own `address-card` `div` since it seemed like they were logically grouped together. Giving that a `display: flex` as well helps the spacing within the element so the text can stretch to 1 line or wrap. Then I used `justify-contents: space-between` on the parent div to push the address container away from the pin.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 25vw; /* just test value - lower this value to see collapsing happening */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* this is your spacing rule */
}

.address-card {
  display: flex; /* helps items be inline and take up space correctly */
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.pin {
  border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="address-card">
    <div class="text">1533 Sylvia Dr, Bristol, Maine</div>
    <img class="close" src="https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/close.svg" height="18" />
  </div>
  <img class="pin" src="https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/map-pin.svg" height="18" />
</div>
```

Comment: I can't wrap address-text and address-close elements together because in a different breakpoint (e.g. large desktop size), the elements are all reversed.  That's why I chose flexbox so that I could rearrange them with a media query using the `order` attribute.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's key information. So in other breakpoints the close icon is before the text? Or is it just the pin icon that moves from the right to the left?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have a gray background that encompasses 1st and 2nd flexbox items. I am getting something close but not quite right. There is space between those items.

```
.address-close {
  margin-left: 5px;   <--- remove this
  margin-right: 15px;
  order: 2;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

Once you remove the left margin on the `.address-close` element, the space between the first and second flexbox items is gone.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/35mnex7b/)

Comment: True, but the .address-pin-icon element doesn't align to the right as the container is increased.

Answer (score -1):

The space appears to be coming from the margins you have applied to address-clos etce. I'd remove that and add some padding-right to address-text.

```css
.address-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 38px;
  width: 35vw;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.address-pin-icon {
  order: 3;
  /* margin-left: 15px; */
  /* removed */
  border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
  padding: 5px;
}

.address-text {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  //margin-right: 0px; 
  padding-right: 15px;
  /* added this */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.address-close {
  /*  margin-left: 5px; */
  /* removed */
  /* margin-right: 15px; */
  /* removed */
  order: 2;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-right: 15px;
  /* added this */
}

.address-close>img:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: white">
      <div class="address-container">
        <span class="address-pin-icon"><img src="https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/map-pin.svg" height="18" /></span>
        <span class="address-text">1533 Sylvia Dr, Bristol, Maine</span>
        <span class="address-close"><img src="https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/close.svg" height="18" /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```